# Multiple Storyboards for iPhone 4,5,6 and 6s

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to create an app and got it to run on iPad AND iPhone. But I need it so for the iPhone, It would resize depending on the device you have, like iPhone 6s, or 4, etc. What do I do. How can I make separate storyboards?

EDIT: I currently have:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
}

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainiPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

as my code, so what do I have to add to do separate storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a new storyboard for the iPad.  To add a new storyboard in Xcode go to `File --> New`, under `iOS` select `User Interface` then select the `Storyboard`.  Name it as you have in your code.

My preferred way is to use 1 storyboard and AutoLayout with constraints on the controls based on the Size Class.  This way you're only using 1 storyboard and it's easier to manage.